# How can I fill in "nan" values conditionally?

Tags: python

I want to fill missing values with like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv("E:\\SPEED.csv")
```

Data - [DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmTHy.jpg)

```
Case - 1
if flcass= "motorway", "motorway_link", "trunk" or "trunk_link"
```

> I want to replace the text "nan" with 110

```
Case - 2
if flcass= "primary", "primary_link", "secondary" or "secondary_link"
```

> I want to replace the text "nan" with 70

```
Case - 3
```

> if "fclass" is another value, I want to change it to 40.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, what have you tried so far?

Comment: you could look into boolean indexing (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and `pd.DataFrame.fillna`

Answer (score 0):

With the below example:

```
data = pandas.DataFrame({
  'flclass': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'], 
  'AGU': [float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), 9]
})
```

You can update it using [numpy conditionals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement-conditionally-using-numpy) iterating over your columns starting from 2nd (`[1:]`) - 5th (`[4:]`) in your data:

```py
for column in data.columns[1:]:
     data[column] = np.where((data['flclass'] == 'b') & (data[column].isna()), 110, data[column])
```

Or [panadas apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```py
import numpy as np

data['AGU'] = data.apply(
     lambda row: 110 if np.isnan(row['AGU']) and row['flclass'] in ("b","a") else row['AGU'],
     axis=1,
)
```

where you can replace `("b","a")` with eg `("motorway", "motorway_link", "trunk", "trunk_link")`

Comment: First of all thank you for your response. I tried what you said, but all lines belonging to the condition I specified (for example "fclass" = "motorway") became 110. I just wanted to change the "nan" values and keep the other values constant.

Comment: I've updated the answer, give me 5 minutes and I will provide you even better answer.

Comment: Just iterate over columns omitting these you don't want to change - I've updated the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It really worked for me. I am thankful to you. :)

Comment: You can accept my answer if it suits you :) - https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

Two ways in pandas:

```
df = DataFrame(

        {

            "A": [1, 2, np.nan, 4],

            "B": [1, 4, 9, np.nan],

            "C": [1, 2, 3, 5],

            "D": list("abcd"),

        }

    )
```

1. [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) lets you fill NA's (or NaNs) with what appears to be a fixed value:

   df['B'].fillna(12)

   [1,4,9,12]
2. [interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) uses scipy's interpolation methods -- linear by default:

   df.interpolate()

   df['A']

   [1,2,3,4]

Comment: This will fill all nan with only one value, which is not the OP case.

Comment: fillna will, interpolate won't and I was giving both for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers. However, as there are 6812 rows and 16 columns (containing nan values) in the data, it seems that different solutions are required.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import pandas as pd
import math

def valuesMapper(data, valuesDict, columns_to_update):
    for i in columns_to_update:
        data[i] = data[i].apply(lambda x: valuesDict.get(x, 40) if math.isnan(x) else x)
    return data

data = pd.read_csv("E:\\SPEED.csv")
valuesDict = {"motorway":110, "motorway_link":110, "trunk":110, "primary":70, "primary_link":70, "secondary":70, "secondary_link":70}
column_to_update = ['AGU_PZR_07_10'] #columns_to_update is the list of columns to be updated, you can get it through code didn't added that as i dont have your data
print(valuesMapper(data, valuesDict, columns_to_update))
```